# Model updating after dom change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using bPopUp Jquery Plugin to make modal.

In my angular App, I am using event broadcast to pass variables from a scope to another.

The problem I have is that if I don't use timeout before call the modal, it won't use the new model updated but placeholder will be "nameBefore" and not the value `attrs.folderName`.
So it work with the timeout but do you have an idea of how to do without ?

note that it also work if I put the timeout on `$scope.folderToEdit = {name: name,key: key};`

Here my html

```
<body>
<layout>
    <menu>
    </menu>
    <wrappers>
        <article ng-repeat="folder in folders">
                            <!-- some html -->
            <editFolder folder-name="folder.name" folder-key="folder.key"></editFolder>
        </article>
    </wrappers>
</layout>
<div folderEditPopUp>
          <input type="text" placeholder="{{folderToEdit.name}}"></div>
</body>
```

Here my javascript.

```
app.directive('folderEditPopUp', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: function($scope, $rootScope){
            $scope.folderToEdit = {
                    name: "nameBefore",
                    key: "key"
                };
            $rootScope.$on("folderEdition", function (event, name, key) {                    
                $scope.folderToEdit = {
                    name: name,
                    key: key
                };
            });
        }
    }
});

app.directive('editFolder',['$rootScope', '$timeout', function ($rootScope, $timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<a><img src="img/bt-edit.svg" alt="Modifier"></a>',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.bind("click", function(){
                $rootScope.$broadcast("folderEdition", attrs.folderName, attrs.folderKey);

                $timeout(function(){
                    $(attrs.thePopUp).bPopup(); 
                }, 50);

            })
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Why don't you call `bPopup()` in the folderEditPopUp directive?
After getting the event, change the values, and show the popup!

Comment: because I thought it shouldn't be done in a controller but only in the link functions of directives ?

Comment: Plus, I just tried to put `$element.bPopup();` after or before changing the values, and it doesn't work either :(

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: I began one, but how to add bPopUp plugin ? http://jsfiddle.net/bastio/CCFA2/

Comment: add http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/assets/jquery.bpopup-0.9.4.min.js to the external sources?

Comment: I did, but got a problem it doesn't seems to work. `TypeError: undefined is not a function` at the line of `.bPopup()`...